# Anaconda Base Environment

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, anaconda, environment

I'm doing this Python course and it asks to install a couple packages:

OpenCV3

```
 conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/menpo opencv3
```

TensorFlow

```
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow
```

Instead of working on this base environment, I've made a clone of it and I installed the packages using the following command:

```
conda create --name test --clone base
```

the environment apparently clones correctly but I get "kernel died" messages when I try to run OpenCV3 codes.

Simple codes like math operations, variable assignments and so on, works fine.

The only way I found to make it work was to install the course packages in the base environment just like the course instructs but I find it's kind of clumsy and non-sense to do so because I might want to make this portable to other systems later.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: When you install TensorFlow in your `test` environment, do you first install pip in that environment

Comment: "the environment apparently clones correctly but I get "kernel died" messages when I try to run OpenCV3 codes." So, presumably you are running a jupyter notebook? Does when you run it normally?

Comment: If you are running on a GPU, it might be worth checking if the GPU drivers are up to date.